# Can I disable comments by default on my YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, comments

Comments are unfortunately always automatically enabled when I upload a video to YouTube either via their website or iPhoto, but more often that not I later manually disable comments for each uploaded video by following the steps from the ["comments on my videos" section of YouTube Help](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171666).

I would much rather have comments automatically disabled, that is to say, disabled by default, for all of my uploaded videos.  Is this possible?  I couldn't find a setting for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an option at /account_defaults under **Comments and Responses** that allowed me to uncheck **Allow comments**.

Comment: That link now links to someone's channel.

Answer (score 3):

For the new YouTube format:

1. Sign in
2. Click your channel username toggle bar (upper right)
3. Click "My channel"
4. Click "Settings" on the "activity"
5. Click "disable allow channel comments"

Comment: Thank you for trying, but you forgot a step (clicking "Feed") and this seem to only disable comments on my **channel**.  I'm trying to disable comments on each of my **videos**.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a channel you can do it by removing the comment module from the modules section in "My channel" settings

Steps

1. Click your user name
2. Select My channels from drop down menu
3. Select "Modules" from the top navigation
4. Uncheck "Comments"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which I just investigated, but that would only affect comments on **my channel** and what I'm really interested in is disabling comments on each of my videos.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option, to disable comments by default.
The only way appears to be through "My Videos" Page where your edit videos to disable comments for each one.